# WIX Use File Permission In Condition

Tags: wix, installation, conditional-statements, file-permissions

My installer fails when it tries to write a shortcut to the desktop when it doesn't have permission to write to the desktop.

(I know the best solution is to simply give the appropriate permissions, and we actually do this, but my boss INSISTS on allowing the installation to continue successfully should the permission to write the shortcut to the desktop be denied and he has instructed our team to test it by intentionally denying that permission.)

So, other than setting the appropriate permissions, is it possible to write a file only if writing permissions for that folder exist?  I thought perhaps I could put in a Condition element that checks file permissions.  Is that possible?

I'm not very familiar/comfortable with WIX, so I may be overlooking something painfully obvious to a veteran.

Comment: How are you writing this shortcut to the desktop?

Comment: It's in a .wxs file, just in a component.  I just took over the project, and it's my first WIX project. 

Essentially it's:

<wix>
    <Fragment>
        <component>
            <file>
                <shortcut>
                </shortcut>
            </file>
        </component>
    </fragment>
</wix>

Comment: Can you put a sanitized (just remove sensitive names) snippet of the whole `<component>` which defines the file and shortcut? Also, probably include the `<Directory>` info so we can see the structure of your directories. This may be an issue with per-machine/per-user installs? Need more info about the actual structure of your installer to know. Another useful bit of info would be running `msiexec /l*v log.txt /i installer.msi` to get a log of your install and you can post the error in it here so we can see exactly what happens when it fails.

Comment: Here you go
<Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="the id" Directory="DesktopFolder">
            <Component Id="theid" Guid="{}">
                <Shortcut Id="theShortcutId"
                            Name="the name"
                            Description="the description"
                            Target="[INSTALLFOLDER_SERVER]File.exe"
                            WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER_SERVER"
                            Icon="icon.ico" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment

Yeah, I might not know enough about this to get help from you.